# JWT Token valid by JwtSecurityTokenHandler but no valid by JWT IO

Tags: token, rsa, x509certificate2

My token is generate from X509Certificate2

My problem:

Validation works via JwtSecurityTokenHandler but not when I go to jwt.io

```
    public static  bool ValidateToken(string token, X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var securityKey = new X509SecurityKey(certificate);

        /*var rsaSecurityKey = new RsaSecurityKey(certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey())
        {
            KeyId = "S5669243590045587695"
        };*/

        var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = securityKey,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authorizationServer"] + "/realms/" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["realm"],
            ValidIssuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientID"],
            
            
        };

        SecurityToken validatedToken;
        try
        {
            tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
        }
        catch (Exception _ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

But not when I use jwt.io

[image]

I fill in my public key

Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_cert.GetPublicKeyString()))

Do you have an idea ?

Thx

Comment: Can you post an example (token, certificate) to reproduce the problem?

Comment: `Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_cert.GetPublicKeyString()))` -- what's that? You are getting ASCII bytes of hex characters, not values. This isn't going to work.

Comment: With `certificate.GetRSAPublicKey().ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()` you can export the public key in X.509 format. The website expects a PEM encoded key in this format, so you must still Base64 encode the data (with the standard and not the url variant) and add the header (`-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----`) and footer (`-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, it's working fine now with PEM