# JWT Token valid by JwtSecurityTokenHandler but no valid by JWT.IO - IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, jwt, identityserver4, jwk

We use IdentityServer4 and the generated tokens are accepted by the Token middleware.
But the token validation on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) fails

I've already tried the validation on jwt.io with PEM and JWK. Both fails.
As supposed here: [Other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65022361/jwt-token-valid-by-jwtsecuritytokenhandler-but-no-valid-by-jwt-io)

If I do the same with another IdentiyServer Instance but same configuration (IdentityServer3) It works, but the JWK looks different.
(no x5c / c5t)

- Are there other tools to check why the validation is failing?
- Can the other JWK format be related to this (x5t / x5c)? And if so, can i Configure IdentyServer to return the 'old format' ?
- Any other Ideas?

To check the token without middleware i wrote this small piece of code:

```
var jwksJson = @"
{
  ""keys"": [
    {
      ""kty"": ""RSA"",
      ""use"": ""sig"",
      ""kid"": ""0313B7152576EF7415003F309C7E7F5EABADD0B7RS256"",
      ""x5t"": ""AxO3FSV273QVAD8wnH5_Xqut0Lc"",
      ""e"": ""AQAB"",
      ""n"": ""3FOm0...J0"",
      ""x5c"": [
        ""MI....=""
      ],
      ""alg"": ""RS256""
    }
  ]
}  
";
var token = "ey...ktYx7QBZw";
var jwks = new JsonWebKeySet(jwksJson);
var jwk = jwks.Keys.First();

var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    IssuerSigningKey = jwk,
    ValidateLifetime = false,

    ValidateAudience = true,
    ValidateIssuer = true,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    ValidAudiences = new []{"aaaa","bbbb","ccc"}, // Your API Audience, can be disabled via ValidateAudience = false
    ValidIssuer = "https://dev.xxxx.xxxx.com"  // Your token issuer, can be disabled via ValidateIssuer = false
};

WritePem(jwk);

if (ValidateToken(token, validationParameters))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Token Valid");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Token Invalid");
}

static bool ValidateToken(string token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
{
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    try
    {
        tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out var validatedToken);
        return validatedToken != null;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        return false;
    }
}

static void WritePem(JsonWebKey jsonWebKey)
{
    var key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    key.ImportParameters(new RSAParameters
    {
        Modulus = Base64Url.Decode(jsonWebKey.N),
        Exponent = Base64Url.Decode(jsonWebKey.E)
    });

    var pubkey = Convert.ToBase64String(key.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo());
    const string pemHeader = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----";
    const string pemFooter = "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
    var publicKeyPem = pemHeader + Environment.NewLine + pubkey + Environment.NewLine + pemFooter;
    Console.WriteLine(publicKeyPem);
}
```

Comment: Make sure your AccessTokenType is JWT for your client.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a new certificate and it works now. I've no idea why the old certificate did not work.